# Use mutable variables when using GraphQl in Gatsby

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm using aliases for several different graphql queries with identical structures but different filters in my Gatsby project. I would like to use a variable when calling the query identifiers, but I'm not sure how to get started.

As an example, let's suppose my GraphQl looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';

const Component = ({ pageContext, data }) => (
  <Layout pageTitle={pageContext.name}>

    // Replace the [pageContext.aliasVariable] below with alias1 or alias2 supplied by the Gatsby Node API via pageContext 

    data.[pageContext.aliasVariable].edges.map(({ node, i }) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <Link to={`/some-where/${node.slug}`}>
          <h2>{node.title}</h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
    
  </Layout>
);

export const query = graphql`
query things ($id: String = "") {
    alias1: parentNode(filter: { firstFilter: { someId: { eq: $id } } }) {
      edges {
        ...myData
      }
    }
    alias2: parentNode(filter: { secondFilter: { someOtherId: { eq: $id } } }) {
      edges {
        ...myData
      }
    }
  }


export default Component;
```

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's doable or if it has some hidden caveat but the approach to follow should be:

```
const Component = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  let { yourAliasedVariable } = pageContext;

  return <Layout pageTitle={pageContext.name}>

    // Replace the [pageContext.aliasVariable] below with alias1 or alias2 supplied by the Gatsby Node API via pageContext 

    data.yourAliasedVariable.edges.map(({ node, i }) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <Link to={`/some-where/${node.slug}`}>
          <h2>{node.title}</h2>
        </Link>
      </div>
    
  </Layout>
};
```

You just need to get your aliased variable from the context using a destructuring:

```
let { yourAliasedVariable } = pageContext;
```

And just use it to get the nested data.